# Can I use `sapply` in R to prepare a histogram multiplot?

Tags: r, histogram

I want to plot 3 histograms on one canvas:

```
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100, 1, 2)
z <- rnorm(100, 2, 3)
par(mfrow=c(3, 1))
sapply(list(x, y, z), hist)
```

All I get is a histogram of `z`. Is it possible to do this using `sapply`?

Comment: OK here, too.  Can you post your `R` version, OS, etc?

Comment: Since apparently you want to loop only for a side effect and don't need a return value, I would use a `for` loop here: `for (x in list(x, y, z)) hist(x)`

Comment: Carl Witthoft is asking for the output of `sessionInfo()` ;)

Comment: `> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] de_CH.UTF-8/de_CH.UTF-8/de_CH.UTF-8/C/de_CH.UTF-8/de_CH.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
`

Comment: I'm mostly wondering if I'm using `sapply` correctly. Does it matter if I'm doing this at the interactive prompt or within a script?

Answer (score 2):

I would use `ggplot2` to create multiple histograms. The advantage is that `ggplot2` treats the multiple plots as one big plot with sub-plots, keeping x-axes and y-axes equal for you (which normal `hist` will not do).

In code:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)           # ...for melt
dat = data.frame(x, y, z)   # Put into one big data.frame
dat_melt = melt(dat)        # Change structure of the data a bit
ggplot(dat_melt, aes(x = value)) + geom_histogram() + facet_wrap(~ variable)
```

[image]

Comment: ++ for answering the problem, not the 'fix this' question :-).  Jim Holtman would approve.